# ng-repeat being commented out

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following test app in which I'm using AngularJS to try and display options in a select.

JS

```
var ClarityApp = angular.module("Clarity", ["ngResource"]);
  ClarityApp.controller("HeaderController", function ($scope, clientData) {
    $scope.ClientList = clientData.getClients();
    $scope.ClientList.then(
    function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
    function (f) {
      console.log(f)
    }
  );
});

ClarityApp.factory("clientData", function ($resource, $q) {
  var client = $resource("/api/client", { isArray: true });
  return {
    getClients: function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      client
      .query(
        {}, //params
        function (event) { deferred.resolve(event); },
        function (response) { deferred.reject(response); }
       );
      var promise = deferred.promise;
      return promise;
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
    <li>
      <label>Client</label>
      <select ng-repeat="Client in ClientList">
        <option>{{ Client.ClientName }}</option>
      </select>
    </li>
```

JSON Return From Server:

```
[
  {
      "ClientID": 3,
      "ClientName": "Client1"
  },
  {
      "ClientID": 4,
      "ClientName": "Client2"
  }
]
```

When I run the app, the ng-repeat portion is commented out. There aren't any errors being returned.

Comment: You probably want to repeat the `<option>`, not the `<select>`, right? Anyway, use [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead.

Comment: I've changed ng-repeat to ng-options and now I'm getting the expression being printed i.e {{ Client.ClientName }}

Comment: Check the documentation page I've linked. There is some additional modifications to do.

Comment: You can't repeat `ClientList` because it is a promise, not the data returned in the promise. You are assigning to scope incorrectly. Call the service function and assign to scope inside the promise callback

Comment: Thanks charlie. That worked :)

Comment: Is it preferable to avoid promises in this case?

Comment: no, just use them properly. There is no need to assign the promise to the controller scope